# created a 100 Bytes file containing zeros .but i cant see zeros

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to create a 100 Byte file of zeroes.
I used the script:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=zero_file_100B bs=50 count=2
```

It works fine, but when I do `cat zero_file_100B` it does not print anything. What might be the reason for that?

Comment: Numeric `0` isn't the same as ASCII `'0'`

Comment: Try `hexdump -C 100B.file`.

Comment: Try `dd if=/dev/zero bs=50 count=2 | tr '\0' '0' > zero_file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for that is the character with ASCII code `0` has no graphical representation in your terminal emulator, which is the expected behavior. You should't confuse it with the character `'0'` which has ASCII code `48`.

To view binary data a portable way, you might use `od`:

```
od -v -t u1 zero
```

Comment: Also depends on your terminal.  It could display as `^@` or � or a number of other representations. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: @tripleee you are correct. I actually wrote: "it has no representation in **your** terminal emulator" already implying it can have some in others.

Comment: Sure; my comment is more aimed at future visitors, who might experience different symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

> but when I do cat zero_file_100B it does not print anything

perhaps you were looking for this

```
$ printf "%0*d" 100 0 > 38650594
$ ls -l 38650594
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 100 Jul 29 10:32 38650594 # Size is 100 bytes.
```

Comment: What an odd name for a file name, even if it is even ;-) .

Comment: @jlliagre : It's nothing but the SO question number ;)

Comment: Got it! I would have used Q38650594 or SO-38650594 though.

Comment: Nice suggestion,, thinking about implementing it in the imminent future

Answer (score 1):

What do you want with zero?
You already succeeded in \0, you can print '0' with

```
for i in {1..100}; do printf 0; done`
```

Slower than other solutions, but you can change this for other requirements:

```
# create file with size 100 only containing strings "zero"
for i in {1..25}; do printf "zero"; done

# create file with size 100 only containing strings "zeros"
for i in {1..20}; do printf "zeros"; done
```